# Uploading object to S3 with Java AWS SDK and access point

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm working with AWS Java SDK and I want to upload objects to a bucket using access point instead of bucket name. Is it possible?

I want to do it by using access point because the bucket's public access is closed but the access is granted through an access point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can perform `PutObject` using the access point.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-points-usage-examples.html#access-points-service-api-support) is the list of all the supported operations using access points.

Simply use the access point `ARN` in place of the bucket name.
`arn:aws:s3:<bucket-region>:<accountNumber>:accesspoint:<access-point-name>`

Works fine with both Java SDK v1 and v2. Tested on `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.1004` and `software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.16.47`

Sample code AWS Java SDK 1.x:

```
String bucketName = "arn:aws:s3:<bucket-region>:<accountNumber>:accesspoint:<access-point-name>";
String filePath = "/Users/user/sample.txt";
String key = Paths.get(filePath).getFileName().toString();
final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
   .standard()
   .withRegion(Regions.<bucket-region>)
   .build();
try {
   s3.putObject(bucketName, key, new File(filePath));
} catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
   // handle exception or throw
   throw e;
}
```

Sample code AWS Java SDK 2.x:

```
String bucketName = "arn:aws:s3:<bucket-region>:<accountNumber>:accesspoint:<access-point-name>";
String filePath = "/Users/user/sample.txt";
String key = Paths.get(filePath).getFileName().toString();
S3Client s3Client = S3Client
   .builder()
   .region(Region.<bucket-region>)
   .build();
try {
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest
       .builder()
       .bucket(bucketName)
       .key(key)
       .build();
    PutObjectResponse putObjectResponse = s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest, Paths.get(filePath));
    System.out.println(putObjectResponse.sdkHttpResponse().isSuccessful());
} catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
    // handle exception or throw
    throw e;
}
```